# centos как открыть порт на iptables

Tags: linux, centos, iptables

У меня CentOS 6

Как открыть для адреса `10.10.10.100` порт `123` в `iptables`. Что бы хост с адресом `10.10.10.100` мог зайти на мой centos по этому порту `123`.

Comment: а вот не надо ничего «закрывать». пока не знаете **как**, а главное, **для чего** вам может понадобиться что-то «закрывать», протсо не делайте этого. от слова вообще.

Comment: ну а на самом деле вам явно [требуется совсем не то, о чём вы задали вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/178576). вернитесь «к началу цепочки» вместо изложения здесь её самого последнего звена.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавит правило первым, т.к. я не знаю, какие еще настройки есть в вашем фаерволе.

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -s 10.10.10.100 -p tcp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Скорее всего тут будет udp.

Comment: Я исходил из того, что 123 - это пример. Т.ч. не знаю, что там. Надеюсь, что очевидно, что если протокол `udp`, то надо поменять `tcp` на `udp`.